# Constructing $k$-morphisms between algebraic curves

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves, morphism

Let $k$ be a finite field containing a sixth root of unity $\xi_6$. Let $C: t^2 = s^6 - 1$ be an hyperelliptic curve over $k$. Let $E': \eta^2 = \xi^3 + 1$ be an elliptic curve over $k$. I am trying the determine the group of $k$-morphisms $\text{Mor}_k(C,E')$. Is there a systematic way of approaching this problem? I have found some morphisms such as $(s,t) \mapsto (-s^2,it)$ (only possible if $k$ contains $i = \sqrt{-1}$) or $(s,t)\mapsto (-\xi_6^2s^2,it)$, but I fail to construct more. How does one find more morphisms (if there are any). How does one determine there are no more. I am aware of this being a hard problem in general, but I was wondering whether there are some techniques one can use in specific cases.

Comment: How is it a group? The affine curve $E'$ has 6 automorphisms $(\xi,\eta)\to (\zeta_3^m \xi,\pm \eta)$. Composing with the Frobenius $(\xi,\eta)\to (\xi^p,\eta^p)$ you get infinitely many morphisms $E'\to E'$ that you can compose with a morphism $C\to E'$.

Comment: In addition to the automorphisms of $E'$ as explained by reuns, you can also use translations on the elliptic curve, because you don't seem to have a base point with a known image. If in need of more information I would try and find field homomorphisms of the respective function fields $k(E')\to k(C)$. Hurwitz's formula says something about the ramification, and it may be possible to move that to specified points using the group operation of $E'$.

Comment: Wait a minute! We can also postcompose by any isogeny of $E'$, cannot we? I give up on this one, but user who actually know some AG can say something intelligible.

Comment: Essentially Mor(C, E) modulo the translations form a group isomorphic to Hom(Jac(C), E) (morphisms of abelian varieties). In turn, the rank of this free abelian group is can be expressed in terms of the zeta functions of C, E. (See Oesterlé "Empilements de sphères").