# Rank of $E: y^2 = x^3 + t^{p+1} + 1$ over $k(t)$ with $k = \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ and $p \equiv -1 \mod 6$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

This is part of of my ongoing masters thesis and I was hoping someone has a good idea. I have the elliptic curve in my title and we can define the algebraic curve $C:s^6 = t^{p+1} + 1$ over $k$. Then the function field $k(C)$ is a degree 6 Galois extension of $k(t)$ and using an very old result (1966) from Tate and Shafarevich I concluded that the Mordell-Weil rank of $E(k(C))$ equals $10(p-1)$. From another reference I know that the rank of $E(k(t))$ must be $2(p-1)$ and I am wondering if anyone knows a way to get this from $r(E(k(C))) = 10(p-1)$. Maybe decompose using the Galois group? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: I guess you computed the rank 10(p-1) via the method I sketch in my comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4392205/constructing-k-morphisms-between-algebraic-curves)? You indeed found 4 times the genus of C (see your question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4458950). And the 2(p-1) is due to Shioda (1991), I suppose?  $$ $$  If $C$ were hyperelliptic, i.e. k(C) / k(t) quadratic, we could certainly relate the L-functions L(E / k(C)) and L(E / k(t)) by considering the Galois-quadratic-twist of E. But here the extension has degree 6, and this is not clear how to proceed.

Comment: I had thought about a similar case where I had cubic twists, and it did not work out. One issue is that the L-function of a cubic twist E' of E is _not_ a cubic twist L(E, \chi, T) of L(E, T), because L(E', T) has integral Dirichlet coefficients, while the cubic character chi would take complex-non-real values.

Comment: Where are you studying, by the way ;-)?

Comment: @Watson Indeed, the rank $10(p-1)$ is found using the method you sketched yes. It works quite nicely cause $C$ is an $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$-maximal curve, so its zeta function can be determined. The rank $2(p-1)$ is Theorem 13.42 in the book Mordell-Weil Lattices by Schutt and Shioda. I indeed tried to replicate the quadratic twist case, for our Galois group of order 6. However, nothing seems to get anywhere and stuff gets messy quite quickly. I study in Groningen, The Netherlands btw!

Comment: Cool! Let me know if you find a way to get deduce the rank of E(k(t)) from E(k(C)). But somehow your computations should allow to compute the rank of E(k(t)) anyway via L-functions. I can explain in more detail if needed. This is actually a work in progress on my side!

Comment: What other questions are you interested in during this master's project :-) ?

Comment: @Watson Some insight in computing the rank via L-functions would be cool! Maybe we can talk somewhere else?